# Why do some web apps log you into a different subdomain?

Tags: web-applications

Some websites house their public parts and their login-protected parts under different subdomains, so that the public site is under "www.somesite.com" or naked "somesite.com", and then logging in takes you to "app.somesite.com". (e.g. log into netflix, and you end up in movies.netflix.com)

Are there any practical reasons for doing this, with respect to security or anything else?

Comment: All I can think of in that case is to split up server farms or allowing the site to be split up.  In the case of Netflix, one site for marketing/advertising and another for watching the movies. This would also allow the sites to be updated on different schedules.  I am pretty sure the marketing site gets updated all the time. I would love to hear an answer from someone who actually knows though...

Comment: Not a bad answer John- maybe the only one? I'll give you some vote love if you make it one.